# Eta reduce and DuplicateRecordFields language extension

Tags: haskell

Issue is about having 2 data types, `Transaction` and `FormatModel`, both having `formatId` field. To prevent adding type signatures to get `formatId` from a `transaction` or `formatModel`, I have created type class `HasFormat`:

```
class HasFormat a where
  formatId_ :: a -> FormatId

instance HasFormat Transaction where
   formatId_  x = formatId x -- gives error because ambiguous occurrence ‘formatId’

instance HasFormat FormatModel where
  formatId_  = formatId -- this works
```

Can some explain why the instance which has eta reduced implementation is working and the other one not?

Comment: These instances are different: `HasFormat Transaction` vs `HasFormat FormatModel`. So, there's more than an eta between them, it seems?

Comment: @chi I do not see why they are more different than eta reduce.

Comment: `instance HasFormat Transaction where formatId_ = formatId` differs from `instance HasFormat Transaction where formatId_ x = formatId x` only by an eta, the instances above differ by an eta AND the involved type.

Comment: @chi point is that they have both `formatId` field

Answer (score 6):

Disambiguation of duplicate record fields is necessarily a best-effort kind of thing because it needs to occur *before* type checking (you can't generally type check an expression before you know what identifiers the names in it refer to; which is what the disambiguation is doing).

Your non-working example is equivalent to this non-working example from the [documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#selector-functions):

```
data S = MkS { x :: Int }
data T = MkT { x :: Bool }
bad :: S -> Int
bad s = x s
```

Comment: It feels a bit odd, though, when the eta-contracted version is allowed. Doesn't that also need some type information to disambiguate?

Comment: @chi From the docs: "we do not infer the type of the argument to determine the datatype". The first version does not work because it would have to look at the type of the argument. The second version works because there is no argument - the correct `formatId` is chosen based on the type of `formatId_`. It is as if one had written `formatId :: X -> Y` as opposed to `formatId (x :: X)`.

Comment: I'm still confused because in the instance declaration I have defined the type for which I do the implementation.

Comment: @user2407038 Your explanation is clear. But in case of the not working version, the correct implemenation could also be chosen from type information because of the type of instance declaration.

Comment: @Rik This is simply not how type checking (in GHC, which is based on the HM type system) works; not in the context of disambiguating record fields, not ever. When `f x` is typechecked, the type of `x` is *never* examined to determine the type of `f`. The class instances have absolutely nothing to with it - within the body of the instance, the function has a monomorphic type anyways. To make things work as you expect, the typechecking algorithm would have to be modified in a very fundamental way. This would be a huge hack, as it would serve no other purpose other than `DuplicateRecordFields`.

Comment: @user2407038 Thanks for explaining!